# How to check data integrity when using NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest?

Tags: nsurlconnection, nsdata, nsurlrequest, integrity

I use sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error method of NSURLConnection class to get NSData from network.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html

```
NSData *urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```

What I want to do is to check if returned value is valid or not.
So, what I did was to compare the length of the data with expected length in response header as below.

```
NSData *urlData;
do {
    urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
    if ([urlData length] != [response expectedContentLength]) {
        NSLog(@"WTF!!!!!!!!! NSURLConnection response[%@] length[%lld] [%d]", [[response URL] absoluteString], [response expectedContentLength], [urlData length]);
        NSHTTPURLResponse *httpresponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *) response;
        NSDictionary *dic = [httpresponse allHeaderFields];
        NSLog(@"[%@]", [dic description]);
    }
} while ([urlData length] != [response expectedContentLength]);
```

However, I don't know if it is enough to ensure the integrity of returned data.
I can't check checksum of the file on the remote server.

Can you share your experience or other tips?

Thanks.

Comment: You are checking the length of the data, not integrity. Depending on how important integrity is to you, you can implement hash based algorithm, or more complicated message-signing, or use HTTPS. But either way, it'll require some server side work. The client hash or sign the message, then the server checks. You mentioned you can't do so on the server side, so integrity can't be ensured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create two variables in the class to store the length of data currently downloaded and the length of data expected (you could do more elegant)

```
int downloadedLength;
int expectedLength;
```

To know the lenght of expected data you have to get it from didReceiveResponse delegate

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{

//    NSLog(@"expected: %lld",response.expectedContentLength);
    expectedLength = response.expectedContentLength;
    downloadedLength = 0;
}
```

to update the downloadedLenght, you have to increase it in didReceiveData:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
downloadedLength = downloadedLength + [data length];
//...some code
}
```

then it is possible to do any logic to compare if downloaded data fit your requirements in connectionDidFinishLoading

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

    if (downloadedLength == expectedLength) {
        NSLog(@"correctly downloaded");
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"sizes don't match");
        return;
    }
}
```

I had to do this to fix HJCache library issues with big pictures that downloaded incomplete (in HJMOHandler).

Comment: I ran into this exact problem with this exact library.  Just wanted to say thanks for explicitly spelling it out.